# Why spring Data JPA does select before update & delete

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA now every-time I perform update or delete Spring data JPA does select before running actual query.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Device d set d.latestDevice = ?1 where d.senderId = ?2")
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
int updateLatestDevice(Device newDevice, Integer senderId);

@Modifying
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
int deleteById(Integer deviceId);
```

I can not find an exact answer to this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate select before update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303691/hibernate-select-before-update)

Comment: Previous question only talks about how to disable select. I am looking for a reason why a select was triggered before update & delete?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the update, I'm actually surprised that it triggers a select.

The delete though triggers events which have the deleted entity as a payload so they need to get loaded.